# SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() sempre retorna 0

Tags: c#, sql, xamarin

Tenho os seguintes códigos:

```
    public async Task EnviaMySQL<T>(string sql,bool pass = false, string file = "SqlJson.php")
    {
        if(!pass)
            Utils.Acoes.Load.ShowLoad();
        var result = "";

        var lista = new List<T>();

        //var gifPass = Utils.Acoes.GetConfig<bool> (c, "gif");

        try
        {
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);

            using (var content = new MultipartFormDataContent())
            {
                content.Add(new StringContent(sql), "sql");
                if (sql.Contains("multi"))
                {
                    sql = sql.Remove(sql.Length - 5);
                    content.Add(new StringContent("multi"), "multi");
                }

                UriBuilder uriBuilder = new UriBuilder("http://" + (new IRealm()).Infopass().Ip);
                uriBuilder.Path += "Toten/" + file;

                HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(new Uri(uriBuilder.Uri.ToString()), content);

                response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                string a = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                var array = JArray.Parse(a.Trim('{', '}'));
                if (!pass)
                    Utils.Acoes.Load.HideLoad();
                OnFinish(array.ToObject<List<T>>());

            }
        }

        catch (Exception g)
        {
            if (!pass)
                Utils.Acoes.Load.HideLoad();
            OnErrorNet(EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }
```

---

```
    public async void InsertMovCaixa(int cd_caixa, string vl, string obs, string cd_cli, string forma, string nm_bandeira)
    {
        var b = new BancoN();
        SetBanco(b);
        await b.EnviaMySQL<Objects.Ficha_Def>($"INSERT INTO mov_caixa(cd_caixa,vl,dt,obs,cd_cli,forma,operacao,nm_bandeira) " +
            $"VALUES({cd_caixa},{vl},NOW(),NULL,NULL,'{forma}','VENDA',NULL) ;");

    }

    public async void SelectLastInsert()
    {
        var b = new BancoN();
        SetBanco(b);
        await b.EnviaMySQL<Item_Ficha_Temp>($"SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();");
    }
```

---

Primeiro faço o `InsertMovCaixa` e depois preciso pegar o `SelectLastInsert`, porém, debugando, percebi que o `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();` está retornando 0 sempre.

Pelo que li, pode ser porque toda fez que envio um `sql` é feita uma nova conexão no banco.

Como posso fazer para isso funcionar?

---

**EDIT:**

Fazendo como o Leonardo sugeriu:

```
response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

Está retornando:

> "Erro ao selecionar: \"INSERT INTO
>   mov_caixa(cd_caixa,vl,dt,obs,cd_cli,forma,operacao,nm_bandeira)
>   VALUES(1,14.4,NOW(),NULL,NULL,'CARTAO','VENDA',NULL); SELECT
>   LAST_INSERT_ID();\" mensagem original:You have an error in your SQL
>   syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version
>   for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()' at line 1"

Também tentei com o `InsertMovCaixa` assim:

```
var b = new BancoN();
SetBanco(b);
await b.EnviaMySQL<Objects.Ficha_Def>($"INSERT INTO mov_caixa(cd_caixa,vl,dt,obs,cd_cli,forma,operacao,nm_bandeira) " +
                $"VALUES({cd_caixa},{vl},NOW(),NULL,NULL,'{forma}','VENDA',NULL); ");

await b.EnviaMySQL<Item_Ficha_Temp>($"SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();");
```

Mas também retorna 0.

Está faltando algo no `EnviaMySQL<T>`? Posso fazer de alguma forma diferente?

Comment: Muito provavelmente você está gerando novas conexões em `var b = new BancoN();`, sendo que o INSERT ID vale apenas para a sessão corrente. Normalmente você deve fazer uma conexão só com o banco e todas as operações necessárias na mesma conexão, até para reaproveitar recursos. A exceção é em caso de operações demoradas fora do DB e necessidade de atender uma quantidade muito alta de clientes simultâneos (o importante é entender as vantagens e desvantagens de cada caso).

Comment: Você usa um código em php para escrever no banco de dados `SqlJson.php`. Há a possibilidade de mostrar esse código pois a abordagem usada pelo op @Leonardo Buta seria suficiente me levando a crer que a consulta dentro do php não retorna valores ou se retorna é um valor fixo.

Comment: Resolvi colocando o `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();` direto no `SqlJson.php`! Obrigado @AugustoVasques

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solução foi colocar o `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();` direto no `SqlJson.php`

Answer (score 3):

Você precisa executar o comando logo após o insert, pois assim ele estará dentro da mesma execução e garantirá que retorne o ID correto.

Seu código ficará da seguinte forma:

```
public async void InsertMovCaixa(int cd_caixa, string vl, string obs, string cd_cli, string forma, string nm_bandeira)
    {
        var b = new BancoN();
        SetBanco(b);
        await b.EnviaMySQL<Objects.Ficha_Def>($"INSERT INTO mov_caixa(cd_caixa,vl,dt,obs,cd_cli,forma,operacao,nm_bandeira) " +
            $"VALUES({cd_caixa},{vl},NOW(),NULL,NULL,'{forma}','VENDA',NULL);" +
              "SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();");

    }
```

Comment: Não funcionou... Fazendo isso o "response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();" retorna: 
"Erro ao selecionar: \"INSERT INTO mov_caixa(cd_caixa,vl,dt,obs,cd_cli,forma,operacao,nm_bandeira) VALUES(1,14.4,NOW(),NULL,NULL,'CARTAO','VENDA',NULL); SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();\" mensagem original:You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()' at line 1"